# In iOS, is there a way to only get the second level of an NSArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

In my NSLog, I am currently getting this:

```
Array: (
    {
    claveTipo = 15;
    color = Azul;
    patron = "A Rayas";
    prendas =         (
                    {
            claveTipo = 15;
            color = Azul;
            patron = "A Rayas";
            precio = 25;
            tipo = BUFANDA;
        },
                    {
            claveTipo = 15;
            color = Azul;
            patron = "A Rayas";
            precio = 25;
            tipo = BUFANDA;
        },
                    {
            claveTipo = 15;
            color = Azul;
            patron = "A Rayas";
            precio = 25;
            tipo = BUFANDA;
        }
    );
    subtotal = 75;
    tipo = BUFANDA;
}
)
```

I only need to show the second level of the Array in a TableView, that is 3 objects, and ignore the first level object that has the same name and keys. How can I discriminate that information?

Comment: doesn't NSArray* a=dats[0].prendas; work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I missed that I have an NSDictionary inside the Array. I solved it like this:

```
  NSMutableArray *productDict = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:20];


for (NSDictionary *dic in self.arregloDeDict) {

    [productDict addObject:dic[@"prendas"]];

}

 NSLog(@"Products: %@", productDict);
```

I hope this helps someone else.